# Is it possible to override the database settings in django for the admin

Tags: django

Is it possible to override the database settings for the admin part? (using django admin)

I want to use a readonly database user for my website but be able to use a read/write user for the admin part, without having to deal with two settings files and two different wsgi processes.

Comment: You mean like groups and permissions? you can have the admin user in the read/write group and the others in a readonly group. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#groups

Comment: how to make the admin use a different database user?
I know you can do this for each model with the routers, but is there a way to do it on the app level?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this with a single instance. However, you can run two instances of your application. On one, you ferry only the requests for the main site and the other only those for the admin. Or you could serve the admin up on a subdomain of your site (all this would be done with your reverse proxy server: nginx, Apache, etc.)

Since you're running two instances, you can customize the settings for each, so you can then also customize the database user being utilized.